# Check cookie on page load and update on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, document-ready

I am trying to if a cookie is set check on page load (`cookieVal = 0`).  If not I want to show a Bootstrap 4 modal that contains two buttons.

If a user clicks the Accept button ("cookiesAccept") then I want to set the `cookieVal = 1`, close the modal and show an `alert` with the cookie value. Note that the alert is for testing only.

The modal and buttons work fine and I am able to show it on page load but I am having trouble as soon as I add the cookie logic which currently does not allow me to click the Accept button and to close the modal.

Can someone tell me what I have to add or change here ?

This is my JS, which is included in the header of every page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkCookie();

  $('#cookiesAccept').click(function() {
    setCookie("privacy", 1, 0);
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    alert("Cookie set to " + privacy);
  });
});

function setCookie(cookie, cookieVal, expiry) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieVal + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
  var name = cookieName + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var privacy = getCookie("privacy");
  if (privacy != 0) {
    alert("Cookie set to " + privacy);
  } else {
    // show cookie modal
    $('.modal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You most likely need to use a delegated event handler in the content of the modal. Try changing `$('#cookiesAccept').click(function(){` to `$(document).on('click', '#cookiesAccept', function() {`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks. I checked but this does not make a difference and I am able to trigger other events with the existing .click function.

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie expires immediately as you provide 0 as expiry value for your setCookie function in your click handler.

```
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

This means current time + (0 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. How would I set it to unlimited so that it does not expire at all ? Or what would be a common value to set here ?

Comment: @Thanks again ! What is a common value to set for such a purpose ? 1 Year ?

Comment: @Justin299 yeah, a year seems fine in this case :-)